# Generate MDX-Query

Tags: c#, ado.net, mdx, azure-analysis-services, mdx-query

I have a cube with several dimensions and measures.

Now, I want to generate a query with all articles [Artikel].[Barcode] combine with colors [Artikel].[Farbe], sizes [Artikel].[Grösse] and warehouses [Filiale-Lagerort].[Filiale-Lagerort]. For each combination I want to select the measures price [Measures].[ART VK-Preis] and quantity [Measures].[LA Bestandsmenge].

The select should only return the combinations where I have a price or a quantity <> 0.

Can someone help me, how I have to generate this query? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the simple version first, which shows the unwanted zero columns? I am guessing the MDX might be something like:

```
SELECT {
 [Artikel].[Barcode].members, 
 [Artikel].[Farbe].members, 
 [Artikel].[Grösse].members, 
 [Filiale-Lagerort].[Filiale-Lagerort].members
} ON ROWS,
{
 [Measures].[ART VK-Preis], 
 [Measures].[LA Bestandsmenge]
} ON COLUMNS
FROM [mycubename]
```

(I've forgotton if you need `.members` or `.children` but the StackOverflow guidelines ask that you show us what you have tried, first, before we can help you.)